# Updating Ubuntu installed on a USB drive

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, usb-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my 16 GB pen drive using Startup Disk Creator, now my pen drive doesn't have write permission, so I cannot format it. But I want to update it to Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10. Can anyone help?

Comment: This could be a language problem; if so I'm sorry. However if the pen drive is not writable, I cannot see how you can `do-release-upgrade` which would upgrade you from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS (the only release-upgrade path open to 16.04 LTS).  You can go from 18.04 LTS to 18.10 (development), but it's not supported here sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New version of a live Ubuntu system

If you want to update the USB pendrive with a new version of Ubuntu, simply **download the iso file and use the Startup Disk Creator to install it**. The old version will be overwritten and the new version will be there.

There will be a live (live-only) system, which can be modified temporarily (in RAM), but the modifications will not persist after shutdown or reboot.

---

Most likely, the USB pendrive is writable, but the file system is not. The Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions is a cloning tool, and it clones the ISO9660 file system from the iso file. This file system is read-only by design.

### Persistent live Ubuntu system

If you want to add some program package or save some files, you can create a persistent live system with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It can save the modifications in a casper-rw partition, so that they persist after shutdown or reboot.

See the following links,

[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a good idea to install an OS on a flash stick. Boot your pc from pendrive, download rufus (you use win as your main system, yes? because it's a windows app) and copy it onto hard drive then install. This app should do with formatting "non-writable" disc.
Or you can try making it accessible for anyone when on linux. Just try sudo chmod 777 /dev/sdx(x is your disc label you can check it with lsblk)

Comment: hello, I have create bootable pendrive using Startup Disk Creator for format any pc/laptop using Ubuntu, like we create bootable pendrive in windows using any tool like you said and many more.